# Использование базового класса в качестве кэш хранилища

Tags: php, ооп

Вопрос такого рода. Есть базовый класс который является кэшом. Теперь нужно перед вызовом дочерних методов смотреть базовый класс и проверять целесообразность выполнения дочерних.

```
interface ICache {

    public function getCategory();
}

abstract class Cache {

    //Вытягиваем из кэша
    public function getCategory() {
        return null;
    }

    //Кладём в кэш
    public function setCategory($data) {
    }
}

class FileProvider extends Cache implements ICache {

    public function getCategory() {
        $data = parent::getCategory();

        if (!is_null($data)) {
            return $data;
        }

        //$data = file_get_content();
        parent::setCategory($data);

        return $data;
    }
}

class DBProvider extends Cache implements ICache {

    public function getCategory() {
        $data = parent::getCategory();

        if (!is_null($data)) {
            return $data;
        }

        //$data = db::query();
        parent::setCategory($data);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

И если наличие методов в дочерних классах решается с помощью интерфейсов, то как заставить дочерние классы вызывать родительский метод перед выполнением? Провайдеров будет множество, и их будут писать другие люди.

Или я не с той стороны зашел?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое решение считается нормой?

```
abstract class Cache {

    //Вытягиваем из кэша
    final public function getCategory() {
        //Эмуляция получения из кэша
        $cache = true ? 'cache' : null;

        if (!is_null($cache)) {
            return $cache;
        }

        $result = $this->loadCategory();
        $this->setCategory($result);

        return $result;
    }

    //Кладём в кэш
    private function setCategory($data) {
    }

    abstract protected function loadCategory();
}

class FileProvider extends Cache {

    protected function loadCategory() {
        return 'query';
    }
}
```

Comment: Решение будет работать пока ктонить не захочет перегрузить getCategory. Если бы вам не нужно было "оберегать" код от других людей, то вролне ок.

Comment: `final public function getCategory()` а если так?

Comment: Чтож с "никак" я погарячился. С final его действительно нельзя будет изменить. Полагаю что это решение безопасно.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя решение с final методом вполне рабочее. Я бы всё же предпочел сделать это через композицию.

Плюс композиции в том что вы сможете комбинировать разные способы кэширования данных с разными способами получения данных.

Более того можно будет кэшировать данные сразу в нескольких местах.

```
interface IProvider{
    public function getCategory();
}

class DBProvider implements IProvider{
    public function getCategory(){
       //non cached code
    }
}

class MemcachedProvider implements IProvider{
    private $provider;
    public function __construct( IProvider $real_provider ){
         $this->provider = $real_provider;
    } 

    public function getCategory(){
          // if in cache return result from memcache
          // in not in cache then use $this->provider and save into cache
    }
}

class SessionCachedProvider implements IProvider{ // just example
    private $provider;
    public function __construct( IProvider $real_provider ){
         $this->provider = $real_provider;
    } 

    public function getCategory(){
          // if value in session then use is
          // otherwise use $this->provider and save into session
    }
}

// обычный provider который ничего не кэшрует
$provider = new DBProvider(); 

// тотже провайдер но эширует в memcached
$cached_provider = new MemcachedProvider( $provider );

// провайдер кэширует в сессии
$session_cached_provider = new SessionCachedProvider( $provider ); 

//кэшируем везде где только можно.
$super_cache = new SessionCachedProvider( $cached_provider );
```

Comment: Либо я не до конца осознал реализацию, либо это не совсем то. Провайдеры в моем случае это сторонние API, БД и файлы которые нужно парсить. Все это с какой-то периодичностью. Чтоб уменьшить нагрузку и пинг от АPI и баз. Решил кэшировать полученные данные, и если они устарели, то провайдер делает запрос, и обновляет их. Сервисы будут дополняться коллегами, поэтому нужно минимизировать и "обезопасить" код в них по максимуму. Базовые методы закрыты, а в провайдерах остаются только методы для получения данных. Поэтому скорее всего остановлюсь на своем. Но спасибо за отклик